# How to restric user to edit and delete other user's post in community discussion?

Tags: community, chatter, chatter-feed

I want to allow user[Login user in community] to modify only the post created by himself and don't want to show delete and edit option on other user's field.Is it possible to restrict user to delete post using same permission that the login user is having.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for a user to see the edit or delete options but not have the permission to edit or delete.

Here is a guide for setting up your Chatter permissions. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_admin_feed_post_editing.htm&type=5

Comment: I have tried this solution previously but it wont affect , user can still delete another user's post.

Comment: In what context are they able to delete a users post? What kind of user are they?